# Write an aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

Can we write an aggregate function for my SQL script.? As I expect that I can make a function as `string_agg` of SQL Server.

```
Select e.EmployeeId, MyAggregateFunction(e.Task, ', ')
From EmployeeTask as e
Group by e.EmployeeId
```

I know I can use `string_agg`. But I want to write it myself to use it in entity framework. Entity Framework cannot translate into `string_agg`.

This is my code in Entity Framework:

```
var result = _context.EmployeeTask.FindAsQueryable().GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeId).Select(x => new {EmployeeId = x.Key, Tasks = DbFunction.MyAggregateFunction(x => x.Task)});
```

I don't want to use .AsEnumrable() before GroupBy().

Comment: Please provide us with sample data and expected results...

Comment: First obstacle is that you can't create aggregate user-defined functions in t-SQL without CLR functions.